# How do I call the store name in php?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, configuration, ce-1.9.0.1, controllers

While testing I've noticed that when a customer creates an account they are shown a message "Thank you for creating an account with English"

Clearly "English" should be replaced with the company name by our default store view name, set by our original developer is "English". If I change the name of the store view in the 'Edit store view section' from "English" to our actual company name will this affect any of Magento's operations? Or is it simply a label?

It would be preferable if the account message called the company name set in config -> General -> Store Information, rather than the store view name. I've found the following code in AccountController.php

```
$this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
            $this->__('Thank you for registering with %s.', Mage::app()->getStore()->getFrontendName())
        );
```

Could this be modified to use the Store Name rather than the Store View Information Name?

Magento 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 0):

You can totally modify it to use what is set in the configuration by using this code instead:

```
$this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
    $this->__('Thank you for registering with %s.', Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_STORE_STORE_NAME))
);
```

Comment: Thanks Raphael,  I have clicked +1 for your answer but my score is hidden because I have a low score myself. The odd thing is that I've edited both AccountController.php and Mage_Customer.csv, the only two places grep finds this message, and when I use SSH and grep again only the original messages are found (?) I've even hard coded our company name into these files and still grep finds the %s string rather than the edited version. Am I missing something??

Comment: @Sparko I'm not sure to be honest. To me that is the right solution. DId you flush the cache ?

Comment: Thanks again for your help, this encouraged me to widen my search, found that our checkout extension was overriding in some way, I've edited the output of their Ajaxcontroller.php file and now have the correct message. I would still be interested to know if renaming the store view to match our company name would cause any problems with core or extensions - this would completely resolve the issue for this and any future upgrades.